# Finding multiple matches and retrieving data based on criteria data set

Tags: excel

I've searched far and wide and can't seem to find exactly what I want.  I tried using INDEX and MATCH but it only pulls one matching.  Arrays would work, but I can't figure out how to do multiple array searches.

So a quick summary of what I need.  I have two spreadsheets.  One contains Orders for Item 1 (Email, Item ordered, QTY, Order#, Name), the second contains "upgrades" to Item 1 (Email, Name, Order#, Item, QTY).  The name column is blank on sheet 2 as the system did not record the names when taking the order.  So now I need to use the email address on Sheet 2 to find all matches on sheet 1 (can be multiple) and pull in the Names associated with the record on Sheet 1.  In this way, we can apply the names of all Item 1 holders to the Upgrades.

On sheet 2, the rows on Sheet 1 that match the email address(column A) from Sheet 2 (also column A) would return all names separated by commas (column E)  into the B column on sheet 2.

How can I accomplish this?

**Note: I would have added screen shots, but the forum won't let me yet :)

Comment: *(can be multiple)* How many?

Comment: Up to about 6, but not more than that.

Comment: Heidi, any chance you can email me the workbook? It would be so much faster. My email address is: daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Comment: Sure. Give me 2 minutes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the ugly array-formula you'll need to retrieve a maximum of six names per email address, each separated by comma:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(ShirtsFull,SMALL(IF(ShirtsEmail=$A1,ROW(ShirtsEmail)),1),5),"")   &   IFERROR(", "&INDEX(ShirtsFull,SMALL(IF(ShirtsEmail=$A1,ROW(ShirtsEmail)),2),5),"")   &   IFERROR(", "&INDEX(ShirtsFull,SMALL(IF(ShirtsEmail=$A1,ROW(ShirtsEmail)),3),5),"")   &   IFERROR(", "&INDEX(ShirtsFull,SMALL(IF(ShirtsEmail=$A1,ROW(ShirtsEmail)),4),5),"")   &   IFERROR(", "&INDEX(ShirtsFull,SMALL(IF(ShirtsEmail=$A1,ROW(ShirtsEmail)),5),5),"")   &   IFERROR(", "&INDEX(ShirtsFull,SMALL(IF(ShirtsEmail=$A1,ROW(ShirtsEmail)),6),5),"")
```